# Laravel 6 relationships: Property [does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel

I'm programming a simple system that allows users to comment videos and reply to a written comment. 
These are the relationships within the models.

```
 //USER MODEL
 public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class,'user_id');
}

//COMMENT MODEL
 public function video()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Video::class);
}


public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}


public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CommentReply::class,'comment_id');
}


//CommentReply model
public function comment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Comment::class);
}
```

This is the code in the blade template for the single video page

```
     @foreach( $video->comments as $comment )
            <li id="li-comment-5">
                <article class="comment even thread-odd thread-alt depth-1 clr" id="comment-5"> 

                        <header class="comment-meta"> <strong class="fn"> {{ $comment->user->name }} </strong> <span class="comment-date">July 4, 2017 7:25 am </span></header>
                        <div class="comment-content entry clr">
                            <p>{{ $comment-body}}</p>
                        </div>

                        <h5>Reply</h5>

                        {{ $comment->replies->body}}
                    </div>
                </article>
            </li>
                @endforeach
```

Everything works fine, but when I try to show the answers to the comment
 **{{ $comment->replies->body}}** 
I get following error
**Property [body] does not exist on this collection instance.**

But if I output the object
  **{{ $comment->replies}}** 
I get all the properties on the screen.

```
[{"id":1,"user_id":1,"comment_id":11,"body":"First reply","created_at":"2020-06-13 20:34:27","updated_at":"2020-06-13 20:34:27"},{"id":2,"user_id":1,"comment_id":11,"body":"Second reply","created_at":"2020-06-13 20:35:06","updated_at":"2020-06-13 20:35:06"}]
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `$comment->replies` is an array - you Need to loop through the replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$comment->replies` is an array so you'll need iterate/loop through each of the replies. Then you'll have access to the body

**Loop through Replies**

```
@foreach($comment->replies as $reply)
    {{ $reply->body}}
@endforeach
```

**Your example code in full**

```
    @foreach( $video->comments as $comment )
        <li id="li-comment-5">
            <article class="comment even thread-odd thread-alt depth-1 clr" id="comment-5">
                <header class="comment-meta">
                    <strong class="fn">{{ $comment->user->name }}</strong><span class="comment-date">July 4, 2017 7:25 am </span>
                </header>
                <div class="comment-content entry clr">
                    <p>{{ $comment-body}}</p>
                </div>

                <h5>Reply</h5>
                @foreach($comment->replies as $reply)
                    {{ $reply->body}}
                @endforeach
            </article>
        </li>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
@foreach( $comment-> replies as $reply )

    {{$reply->body}}

@endforeach
```